# RabbitMQ - Topic Exchange - Same topics two or more consumers

Tags: rabbitmq

I'm nmew to AMQP and trying to work out a notification architecture for a RabbitMQ system.

I want a Topic exchange (NotificationsExchange, let's say), specifically because I want to flexibility with routing keys and queues that comes with the topic exchange as well as more options for future expansion on the topic.  I might be wrong though, because...

I also want to have each notification consumed by two or more consumers.  As a baseline, I want each notification published to wind up in a database.  Additionally, I want each notification to be eligible for consumption by a client application (e.g., web app to consume and further push through sockets for immediate user notification without db polling).

This really sounds like a fanout exhange situation, except I didn't want to do that because I'd need a whole lot more queues to handle the various notifications (I think - still new to AMQP and trying to wrap my head around it).

Is it possible to have two consumers get notified (consistently) from the same queue?

For example:

- Push `Notif.NotifGroup.User.ThisUser` through the NotificationExchange
- Have `dbListener` bind to `Notif.#`
- Have `mvcClientListener` also bind to `Notif.#` (and further determine if the user is online and push downstream via socket)

I'm not sure if I'm on the right track here.  I'm reading that "multiple consumers to the same queue are load balanced in a round robin fashion", and quite frankly, I don't know what that means.

Is it possible to have a Topic Exchange where two consumers can consistently read the same messages from the same queue (e.g., same routing key), or must I go with a Fanout Exchange for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Is it possible to have two consumers get notified (consistently) from the same queue?

yes, but this is not what you want.

when you have multiple consumers on one queue, the consumers are round-robin load balanced. if consumer 1 receives message a, consumer 2 cannot receive it

instead, what you want to do is add additional route handlers for each consumer, and have each consumer create it's own queue.

for example `NotificationEx` may have a binding for `Notif.#` which pushes to `dbQueue`. The same exchange would have a binding for `Notif.#` which pushes messages to `mvcQueue`.

Your database consumer would consume from `dbQueue` and your web app would consume from `mvcQueue`.

This makes it very easy to add new consumers, each with their own queue and binding to the exchange.

---

FWIW, there is not "right" or "wrong" exchange type for any given situation. You can make any exchange type work for any situation. However, some exchange types make it easier to deal with certain situations.

You might want to check out my ebooks on RabbitMQ for more information about exchange types, their generally accepted "best use cases", and how they can be applied in rather interesting scenarios: https://leanpub.com/b/rmq-layout-and-patterns

Comment: Thanks - I hadn't known if I could create two entirely separate queues based on the same "push criteria" (for lack of the correct term - I'll have to look at those details a bit more closely).  As a side note, I just this morning started digging into RabbitMQ and thus AMQP in general, and this is the fourth post of yours I've seen on the topic at SO (and one or two blog posts also maybe?)  I purchased one of the ebooks a few hours ago.  Helpful.

Comment: BTW, if by chance to could throw a quick example as to how to create those separate queues, that'd be great.  If not I'll find it eventually, but I don't think I've come across it quite yet and the tuts at RabbitMQ don't seem to cover that scenario.  Thanks again

Comment: glad my work is being helpful! :) for multiple queues, it works the same way as creating a single queue and binding it to an exchange. there are 2 things you need to do, though: 1) make sure you only have 1 RMQ connection per application instance, and 2) use a new Channel for each consumer. 1 connection, many channels within that connection. Connections are expensive and limited. Channels are cheap, and nearly unlimited. All the real work is done on channels, and it's easiest to have 1 channel dedicated to 1 thing. hope that helps!

Comment: @DerickBailey please help me on this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59213798/rabbitmq-round-robin-distribution-of-messages-with-topic-exchange-with-single