# RabbitMQ : Round robin distribution of messages with Topic exchange with single queue

Tags: rabbitmq

Does RabbitMQ do round robin distribution of messages in following situation ?

> RabbitMQ configuration :
>
> 1. Exchange type - Topic
> 2. Routing key - notify.#
>
> Producer is pushing the message to above exchange with following
> different topics-
>
> notify.log.# , notify.status.#, notify.priceChange.#

There are 4 consumers are running on different servers.

1. 3 consumers are doing the same processing and running on different instance of same application under a load balancer.(They want to consume every message pushed by producer)

   They are listening to "**notification_queue**" attached with routing key **"notify.#"**.
2. Remaining 4th consumer is doing some different processing than first 3 consumers and running on different server(of different application).

   It is listening to "**log_queue**" attached with routing key **"notify.log.#"**.

Will RabbitMQ distribute message in round robin fashion in first 3 consumers(in point 1)?

Please help.

Comment: Yes, it's round-robin, just be aware that if one consumer hangs, the others will still receive messages. So it's not a "fair dispatch". But on average, and over time, they should get the same amount of messages.

Answer (score 2):

Yes indeed , does not matter what is the point of a  origin of  consumer . When we have multiple consumers on the same queue then the distribution is round robin , you can try it out in the simulator here  http://tryrabbitmq.com/